# date() shows the wrong time

Tags: php, mysql, date

When I use `echo date("h:i:s");` I get the wrong time. The minutes and seconds are correct but the hours are wrong.

I tried to use `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');` to get my time zone. This may work and when I call `date("h:i:s");` it shows me the correct time. But when I try to save the time into the database with `current_time('mysql', 1)` it saves it with the wrong time.

How can I fix this?

Comment: save time in form of timestamp and letter convert to current timezone when you want to show

Comment: Both MySQL and PHP have configuration options for default timezones. That might be the best place to set it if your application will always use that zone.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo date("h:i:s");
```

I suppose you are using the 24h format in Berlin.

Better to use:

```
echo date("H:i:s");
```

h lowercase is 12h format, H uppercase is 24h format.

Comment: Also if it's still not ok, post the full code (the H:i:s you are trying to save in db).